# javascript not working well

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a problem with javascript function.
I have a textbox that shouldn't accept other characters just number based on other dropdownlist.
For the first condition ("Leternjoftimi") it works fine, but for the second one "Numri i biznesit" i doesn't work.
Any help?
My function is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(evt) {
       evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
       var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
       var doctype = document.getElementById("ctl00_DefaultContent_FormViewPerson_txtIdType");
       var test = document.getElementById("ctl00_DefaultContent_FormViewPerson_txtIdType1");
       if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (doctype.value == "Leternjoftimi" || test.value == "Numr i biznesit")) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }   
</script>
```

```html
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxIDCode" runat="server" Width="100%" Text='<%# Bind("IDCode") %>' AutoPostBack="true" meta:resourcekey="TextBoxIDCodeResource1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" ></asp:TextBox>
```

And the asp.net code for the lists it should be base:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIdType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%" meta:resourcekey="txtIdTypeResource1" AutoCompleteType="None" OnTextChanged="txtIdType_TextChanged"  ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIdType1" runat="server" AutoPostBack ="true" Width="100%" meta:resourcekey="txtIdTypeResource1" AutoCompleteType="None" OnTextChanged="txtIdType1_TextChanged"  ></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtenderIdType" runat="server"
  CompletionInterval="200" 
  MinimumPrefixLength="0" 
  CompletionListCssClass="listMain"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="itemsMain"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemsSelected"
  OnClientItemSelected="IdTypeSelected"
  ServiceMethod="GetDIVRList_IdType" 
  ServicePath="~/WebServices/AutoCompleteDictionary.asmx"
  TargetControlID="txtIdType" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"  runat="server"
  CompletionInterval="200" 
  MinimumPrefixLength="0" 
  CompletionListCssClass="listMain"
  CompletionListItemCssClass="itemsMain"
  CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="itemsSelected"
  OnClientItemSelected="IdTypeSelected"
  ServiceMethod="GetDIVRList_IdType1" 
  ServicePath="~/WebServices/AutoCompleteDictionary.asmx"
  TargetControlID="txtIdType1" DelimiterCharacters="" Enabled="True">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: `Numri i biznesit` or `Numr i biznesit`?

Comment: actually is "Numri i biznesit", I typed it wrong. I noticed that it matter which I write first. If i write first "Leternjoftimi" first it validates that, but if I write "Numri i biznesit" write it validates that. I don't know why it validates just the first condition

Comment: You want both conditions to be true?

Comment: Yes, I need both conditions to be true

Comment: Then use AND (`&&`) instead of OR (`||`).

Comment: I can't use both at the same time. It may be one or other, but the other textbox that I validate should work for both of them, do  u understand

Comment: Not at all. I give up.

Comment: Ok, listen, I have 2 textboxes txtIdType that contains "Leternjoftimi" and txtIdType1 that contains "Numri i biznesit". Also I have the other textbox TextBoxIDCode wich should be filled with numbers based on the other texboxes wich is choosed 'Leternjoftimi" from txtIdType or 'Numri i biznes it' from txtIdTypeId1

Comment: I've had a quick look and it appears your script is working fine - https://jsfiddle.net/env4xhkw/4/